# Why buttons look different when user is pressing it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
UIImage * imgBtnReloadAllButton = [UIImage resizeableImageWithCapInsets2:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5) withName:@"search_in_this_area"];
[self.btnReloadAllButton setBackgroundImage:imgBtnReloadAllButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];


PO([self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted]);
PO([self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
PO([self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateSelected]);
PO([self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateReserved]);
PO([self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateApplication]);
PO([self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateDisabled]);
```

Simple enough. This is what I see:

```
2013-03-19 15:22:22.349 BadgerNew[1724:c07] [self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted]: <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
2013-03-19 15:22:22.350 BadgerNew[1724:c07] [self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]: <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
2013-03-19 15:22:22.350 BadgerNew[1724:c07] [self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateSelected]: <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
2013-03-19 15:22:22.350 BadgerNew[1724:c07] [self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateReserved]: <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
2013-03-19 15:22:22.382 BadgerNew[1724:c07] [self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateApplication]: <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
2013-03-19 15:22:22.383 BadgerNew[1724:c07] [self.btnReloadAllButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateDisabled]: <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
(lldb) po imgBtnReloadAllButton
$0 = 0x0d6b5a80 <_UIResizableImage: 0xd6b5a80>
```

So it looks like all button states points to the same image, namely image 0xd6b5a80

Yet when user click the button, after pressing the button but before lifting their dirty finger, the button looks different.

Basically when I press the button the bottom corners of the buttons are no longer round.

What happened?

Comment: If you dont want that, just set [self.btnReloadAllButton setBackgroundImage:imgBtnReloadAllButton forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];  [self.btnReloadAllButton setBackgroundImage:imgBtnReloadAllButton forState: UIControlStateSelected];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buttons adjust their image when entering the highlighted state, even if you haven't set a specific highlighted image. To prevent this, use:

```
imgBtnReloadAllButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Comment: What do you mean by adjust?

Comment: I think that would only affect how light the image is. Basically when I press the button the bottom corners of the buttons are no longer round.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would help in the question?

Comment: It's hard to do screenshot because I have to touch it to make it happen.

Comment: Did you try the code? Highlighting adds another overlay to the button. The overlay may be dark, rather than light, and if you have a dark button on a light background, this could have the effect of squaring off the corners. Even a screenshot of the unhighlighted button would be helpful, or you could manually highlight it in code?

Answer (score 0):

This is because iOS renders the image you use as (background) image when you press on the button. You could prevent this by setting the image as image and not as background image.